# How to handle async Rest Error in unit test cases using jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

Following is my node js test file code , This is a unit test case, and its failing. Please find the code and error message in detail below.

```
jest.unmock('./utils.js');
describe('test', () => {
     it('test', async (done) => {
        await expect(getAPISecretKey('testKey')).rejects.toEqual('RestError: AKV10000: Request is missing a Bearer or PoP token.');
     });
 });
```

It's failing with the below error

```
FAIL  src/utils.test.js
  ● test › test

    expect(received).rejects.toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: ["RestError: AKV10000: Request is missing a Bearer or PoP token."]
    Received: [RestError: AKV10000: Request is missing a Bearer or PoP token.]

       6 |      it('test', async (done) => {
    >  7 |         await expect(getAPISecretKey('testKey')).rejects.toEqual(error);
         |                                                          ^
       8 |      });
       9 |  });
      10 | 

      at Object.toEqual (node_modules/expect/build/index.js:241:20)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/utils.test.js:7:58)
```

I tried with following way but still, it didn't work.

```
jest.unmock('./utils.js');
describe('test', () => {
     var error = ['RestError: AKV10000: Request is missing a Bearer or PoP token.'];
     it('test', async (done) => {
        await expect(getAPISecretKey('testKey')).rejects.toEqual(new Error('Request is missing a Bearer or PoP token.'));
     });
 });
```

code of getAPISecretKey

```
async function getAPISecretKey(secretNameStr) {
    let credentials = getKeyVaultCredentials();
    let keyVaultClient = new SecretClient(KEY_VAULT_URL, credentials);
    let secret = await keyVaultClient.getSecret(secretNameStr);
    return secret.value;
}
```

Tried following way and giving an error as follows

```
jest.unmock('./utils.js');
describe('test', () => {
  //toEqual('RestError: AKV10000: Request is missing a Bearer or PoP token.');
     it('test', async (done) => {
        await expect(getAPISecretKey('testKey')).rejects.toThrow('AKV10000: Request is missing a Bearer or PoP token.');
     });
 });
```

Error:

```
 FAIL  src/utils.test.js (14.891 s)
  ● test › test

    : Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:

      4 | describe('test', () => {
      5 |   //toEqual('RestError: AKV10000: Request is missing a Bearer or PoP token.');
    > 6 |      it('test', async (done) => {
        |      ^
      7 |         await expect(getAPISecretKey('testKey')).rejects.toThrow('AKV10000: Request is missing a Bearer or PoP token.');
      8 |       

      at new Spec (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Spec.js:116:22)
      at Suite.<anonymous> (src/utils.test.js:6:6)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/utils.test.js:4:1)
```

Comment: You need to show the code of `getAPISecretKey`

Comment: @slideshowp2 , updated question with the requested code

Comment: Maybe `toThrow` instead of `toEqual`? The exception is likely an object and you're testing for a string. The "Expected" and "Received" values look the same because Error.toString just prints the error message.

Comment: @Cully, thanks for your response, I tried with that as well but getting an error "Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:"  i also updated the questions. please look

Comment: Do you have to `await getAPISecretKey`? It's async. It looks like you're just passing the Promise to `expect`, not the result of `getAPISecretKey`. Actually, nm, looks like maybe you don't need that for `.rejects`

Comment: And try removing `done` from the function. I seem to remember some testing libs checking whether your test takes that param, and then waiting for it to be called. Not sure if that's the case, but worth trying.

Comment: @Cully, you are champ!!, I removed done and it's working will post the answer in detail. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve the issue by removing "done" from the async method arguments as follows.

```
jest.unmock('./utils.js');
//jest.setTimeout(10000);
describe('test', () => {
     it('test', async () => {
        await expect(getAPISecretKey('testKey')).rejects.toThrow('AKV10000: Request is missing a Bearer or PoP token.');
      
     });
 });
```